# ESP8266-01 Upload Sketch Problem Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, arduino-ide, esp

My problem is actually in two stages.
I am very new to arduino uno and 8266-01. I have read many documents and watched videos for nearly 2 weeks, but I cannot even run the simplest "blink" example.

First of all, I installed the compatible software with an esp download tool as follows according to 6014h. And it seems okay.
[image]

After triple check, my wires and connections where they have to .
Rx->Rx  Tx->Tx  CH-3.3v GPI0 grounded Ground->Ground  and also 8266-01 VCC connected to Arduino 5v with 3.3v regulator and connected with capacitor, to debug voltage i check with voltmeter.

Problem is:
When I try to upload simple Blink example below imag.  My IDE gives a very different output from the videos I watched. I could not understand the reason for this.

the IDE outputs on the all of videos that i watched, are while uploading

[image]

This kind of upload starts when it says upload and when it's finished, the program runs.

BUT!In my case my  IDE is acts like that and nothing happens end of the upload.

[image]

My 8266 generic settings are as follows.

[image]

Led out pin in the blink example is 2 and GPI1 is connected to led to blink after all this explanation, where i missed up ?

Why i am taking different uploading process and code is not working?

Comment: Set flash mode to DOUT instead of QIO? You get different output because the videos you have seen are out of date and use an old uploading tool (esptool.exe) rather than the current one (esptool.py) or maybe the OTA tool (espota.py).

Comment: I set the flah mode to DOUT. I uploaded sketch again and hard resetting via rst pin is occured again and not blinking or any other serial AT commands not working. I think i catch somethings but i dont know. Why my code is not running or how I run the code after uploaded ?

Comment: you deleted the AT firmware with sketch upload

Comment: @Juraj how I run sketch ? is there any other connection mode for running mode ?

Comment: buy a development board for Arduino sketches on esp8266. something like Wemos D1 mini. it has USB and controls the flashing mode and reset of the esp8266. with esp-01 you must manually handle io 0 and reset for every upload. I wire buttons to esp-01 for frequent flashing. Then for flashing I hold the button for io 0 and click the button for reset. then I release the io 0 button.

Comment: My general advice these days: forget ESP8266 - use the ESP32. It's so much more capable.

Comment: Do you know whether you have an ESP-01 or ESP-01S? Visually, ESP-01 has two LEDs near the PCB antenna, a Blue LED connects to Tx line (GPIO1) and a Red LED as a power indicator. ESP-01S however only has one Blue LED and it is connected to GPIO2 instead. Based on your Arduino Menu, you are selecting GPIO2 as LED pin which only works for ESP-01S. If you have an ESP-01, you need to change "Builtin Led" to "1". See [my blog](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2020/04/a-better-way-to-use-esp-01-as-wifi-shield/) for more explanation.